# HatDash is live!

Tags: discussion, winterbash

For more info, see the blog:

http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/

Feel free to leave feedback here, but please make new questions for bug reports.

Comment: The parent tag for The Old republic is [tag:star-wars-tor] but the link is for the synonym [tag:swtor]. Not really a bug, but wanted to post.

Comment: *but please make new questions...* so that we can all get the Meta hat!  :D

Comment: @John ...and for the record, I *did* create this post primarily to get my meta hat

Answer (score 4):

There is also a minisite associated with the Hat dash, which can be found at http://hatdash.com/

The minisite also includes [a list of hats](http://hatdash.com/#hats)!

Answer (score 2):

So, the [hat sprite](http://hatdash.com/content/img/hats128.png)  seems to contain a couple more hats than listed on the [Hat Dash minisite](http://hatdash.com/#hats).

Did these simply not make the cut, or could there possibly be… *super-exclusive secret hats*‽

Comment: Some of those *secret hats™* are amazing. I must have them.

Comment: I would tell you, but I'd have to kill you.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/94S5N.png **SECRET HATS CONFIRMED.**

Comment: Hmm, we should have realized you'd find the secret hats in the sprite...

Comment: @DavidFullerton: I award you with the n00b hat. ;p

Answer (score 1):

Inquiry: Does Meta activity count towards Hat Acquisition?

Also Chat Hats? Coming after cacheing sorts itself, or but a fleeting dream, never to be allowed to taste the light of day?

Comment: And if it doesn't, the lack of a specific Meta-hat for meta-activity is a *grave oversight*.

Comment: http://hatdash.com/ -> Ctrl-F -> "meta"

Comment: @balpha missed it somehow! Best hat! And it's **Command-F** You win-normative clod!

Answer (score 1):

The Hat Dash link in the header doesn't stand out, the text is difficult to read and it really doesn't look like a link. When I first visited I automatically skipped over it, and didn't realize I could click on it until [Balpha specifically mentioned that you could](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/800170#800170). I suggest it be changed.

*edit*: The new "get hats", "only until Jan 6th!!" banners kind-of deal with this.